# Moving an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

I originally had my Eclipse projects in this folder: `C:\Users\fresh\Eclipse\QA`
I renamed my username in Win7 to rfresh and in file explorer I do see that the new name is there in `C:\Users\rfresh` and in fact in Eclipse when I create a new Java Project I can see `C:\Users\rfresh\Eclipse\QA` but when I try to select it and use it it gives an error message because somehow Eclipse is still seeing the old path of `C:\Users\rfresh\Eclipse\QA`. How can I get Eclipse to see the new username path? Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete the old project from the `Package Explorer` in Eclipse previously to add the project again.

> Go to Package Explorer > Right click the old project > Delete

Comment: Eclipse still sees C:\Users\fresh\Eclipse\QA and adds the project back into that same folder...

Comment: Well, try to switch Workspace then: `File > Switch Workspace > Other`. Type `C:\Users\rfresh`. This will probably work for all the projects you have, and not only this one.